# Filter value on .keyup method JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, keyup

I have two fields (username and email) and I want to auto-fill the username with the content of the email field, because username is a hidden input.

I just need the contentent before `@domain.com`. Right now I'm using the `.keyup()` but I can use the `.change()` too.

How can I only get the content before `@domain.com`?

```
$('#id_email').keyup(function () {
    $('#id_username').val($(this).val());
});
```

**EDIT:** All answers Works perfectly, thank you so much.

Comment: doesn't make sense doing this using `keyup` before whole address is typed in

Comment: I would encourage you to use the `input` event as opposed to `change` or `keyup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda simplistic but can you do something like

var email = "test@example.com";
var username = email.split('@')[0];

so:

```js
<script>
    $('#id_email').change(function () {
        var email = $(this).val();
        $('#id_username').val(email.split('@')[0]);
    });
</script>
```

It will work but, of course, assumes a valid email address.

Answer (score 2):

An edited version of **[Dustin Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35415821/1076753)** answer, just because I believe that **input** it's better for this kind of stuff instead of **keyup** or **change**, and also we don't need to store any **email** variables.

```
$('#id_email').on('input',function(){
   $('#id_username').val($(this).val().split('@')[0]);
});
```

Check the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/gvamLbm9/)**

Comment: Hope that @Dustin does not get angry ;) I voted his answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#id_email').keyup(function () {
    var usr = $(this).val();
    var usr = usr.split('@');
    $('#id_username').val(usr[0]);
});
```

See how split works: 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

```
$('#id_email').keyup(function () {
    $('#id_username').val($(this).val().split('@')[0]);
});
```